# Is it possible to just move just a single file from one folder to another using DropIt?

Tags: windows-10

My problem is that I want to backup my Chrome bookmarks, but the file doesn't seem to have a file extension so DropIt can't associate it with a task. Can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be done.
Since you only want to backup Chrome bookmarks, you can use absolute path as a rule.
Create a new rule, enter a name, then enter the absolute path of the bookmark file as rule, then define an action, done.